# React-Native app crashes on JS exceptions, gives useless stack info (Android)

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm trying to get my iOS React-Native app working on Android. One thing that is hindering me in this already difficult process is that JS exceptions not only seem to crash the app, but the error report is also not giving me useful line number info. Instead it gives me the URL to the local packager instance. How do I make it not crash on JS errors, and also give me useful stack info so I can properly debug?

EDIT: Also this error doesn't occur when I build and run the app on iOS. I'm only getting it on Android.

[image: screenshot from emulator]

Answer (score 1):

For now I've found a workaround. I put a breakpoint in File.java, where the exception is thrown, and moved up the stack to DevSupportManagerImpl.java where StackTraceHelper.convertJsStackTrace(ReadableArray details) gets called.

ReadableArray can be inspected in the debugger to reveal the actual JS stack information including the real files and line numbers related to the error.